# update models from other model odoo

Tags: python, updates, odoo-10

I want to update a model by another model

for example when I select an employee I want to update his coordinates after the states done

```
    class Hr_transf_employee(models.Model):
        _name = 'hr.employee.transfer'
        _rec_name = 'employee_id'



        date_cration = fields.Date(string='Date order', required=True, default=datetime.today())
        date_transfer = fields.Date(string='Date transfer')
        employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee',string='Employee', required=True) 

        job_id_new = fields.Many2one('hr.job',string='Job title', required=True) 
        country_work_id_new = fields.Many2one('res.country', 'Country work new') 

        state = fields.Selection([
            ('draft', 'Draft'),
            ('accept', 'Accept'),
            ('done', 'Done'),
            ('cancel', 'Cancel'),
        ], string='Order Status', readonly=True, copy=False, store=True, default='draft')
```

I want to update **job_id** by ***job_id_new***
and **country**  by ***country_work_id_new*** 
in the model hr.employee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your done fuction `wkf` to be like :

```
@api.multi
def done(self):
    self.state = 'done'
    if self.job_id_new :
       self.job_id = self.job_id_new.id
    if self.country_work_id_new :
       self.country = self.country_work_id_new.id
```

To get today :

```
if  self.date_transfer <= self.create_date : 
    self.date_transfer = fields.datetime.now()
```

Comment: It works too ____ so if i have a date field and i want to apply function that if date_transfer=< 'date creation' how to do

Comment: thank @khelili miliana ___ Sorry I did not explain my question well
I wanted to say (if self.date_transfer <= self.create_date ) was replaced by state 'done" ; I mean before all  >>>> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261821/update-fields-from-other-fields-after-date-odoo]

Answer (score 1):

First Option:
you can override the 'write' method on hr.employee.transfert and update the employee_id fields

```
@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    res = super(Hr_transf_employee, self).write(vals)

    if vals.get('state', False) == 'done':  # Only update employee if the transferts become 'done'.
        for transfert in self:
            transfert.employee_id.job_id = transfert.job_id_new
            transfert.employee_id.country = transfert.country_work_id_new
    return res
```

Second Option: 
you can add two computed fields on the res.partner model (you can use the same method for the both fields).

```
@api.multi
def my_compute_method(self):
    for employee in self:
        employee_transfert_id = self.env['hr.employee.transfer'].search([
            ('employee_id', '=', employee.id),
            ('state', '=', 'done'),
        ], order="write_date DESC", limit=1)  # Get the last done transfert

        employee.job_id = employee_transfert_id and employee_transfert_id.job_id_new or False
        employee.country = employee_transfert_id and employee_transfert_id.country_work_id_new or False
```

Comment: Thank @Bouh i try the first it's work well ___ so
if i have a date field and i want to apply function that if  today =< 'date creation' how to do

Comment: @developper If that works well, then accept the answer

Comment: OK
Do you have an idea if there is date => today

Comment: You can use fields.datetime.now() to get the current time and filter the self like 
<pre>
date_now = fields.datetime.now()
for transfert in self.filtered(lambda x, date_now=date_now: x.your_date_field => date_now):
    ...
</pre>