# update fields from other fields after date odoo

Tags: python, function, odoo

I want to update a field by another field

for example when I select an employee I want to update his coordinates after the states done

```
    class Hr_transf_employee(models.Model):
        _name = 'hr.employee.transfer'
        _rec_name = 'employee_id'


@api.multi
def transfert(self):
    self.date_cration ==  "date_transfer"
    if self.region_new :
       self.state_work_id = self.region_new.id
    if self.country_work_id_new :
       self.country_work_id = self.country_work_id_new.id


        date_cration = fields.Date(string='Date order', required=True, default=datetime.today())
        date_transfer = fields.Date(string='Date transfer')
        employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee',string='Employee', required=True) 

        job_id_new = fields.Many2one('hr.job',string='Job title', required=True) 
        country_work_id_new = fields.Many2one('res.country', 'Country work new') 

        state = fields.Selection([
            ('draft', 'Draft'),
            ('accept', 'Accept'),
            ('done', 'Done'),
            ('cancel', 'Cancel'),
        ], string='Order Status', readonly=True, copy=False, store=True, default='draft')
```

I want to update **region_new** by ***state_work_id ***
and **country_work_id_new**  by ***country_work_id *** 
in the model hr.employee ***if*** the date_cration  >= date_transfer

i try to add in function self.date_cration >=  "date_transfer" but it's not apply with date

Comment: Please describe more so we can understand what you want to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know [@api.onchange](https://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decorator.html?highlight=api.depends#api-onchange) and [@api.depends](https://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decorator.html?highlight=api.depends#api-depends) decorators ?